# I make the soap call catalogCategoryInfo call

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap, soap-api-v2

I am trying to get a cusotm attribute I created in the categories to show up when I make the soap call catalogCategoryInfo call.

I created the custom attribute using the following code

```
 <?php  require_once "app/Mage.php";

    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
    $installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
    // change details below:
    $attribute  = array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'label'=> 'IceCatID',
        'input' => 'text',
        'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'default' => "",
        'group' => "General Information"
    );
    $installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'IceCatID', $attribute);
    $installer->endSetup();
```

Which worked. I can see and add in values to my categories on the back end and the values hold.
I then edited the file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Api.php

foreach ($collection as $category) {
    /* @var $category Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
    $result[] = array(
        'category_id' => $category->getId(),
        'parent_id'   => $category->getParentId(),
        'name'        => $category->getName(),
        'is_active'   => $category->getIsActive(),
        'position'    => $category->getPosition(),
        'icecat_id'   => $category->getIceCatID(),
        'level'       => $category->getLevel()
    );
}

protected function _nodeToArray(Varien_Data_Tree_Node $node)
    {
        // Only basic category data
        $result = array();
        $result['category_id'] = $node->getId();
        $result['parent_id']   = $node->getParentId();
        $result['name']        = $node->getName();
        $result['is_active']   = $node->getIsActive();
        $result['position']    = $node->getPosition();
        $result['icecat_id']   = $node->getIceCatID();
        $result['level']       = $node->getLevel();
        $result['children']    = array();

        foreach ($node->getChildren() as $child) {
            $result['children'][] = $this->_nodeToArray($child);
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

I also edited teh wsdl.xml to include references to the new attribute

```
<complexType name="catalogCategoryEntity">
        <all>
            <element name="category_id" type="xsd:int"/>
            <element name="parent_id" type="xsd:int"/>
            <element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
            <element name="is_active" type="xsd:int"/>
            <element name="position" type="xsd:int"/>
            <element name="icecat_id" type="xsd:int"/>
            <element name="level" type="xsd:int"/>
            <element name="children" type="typens:ArrayOfCatalogCategoryEntities"/>
        </all>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="catalogCategoryEntityNoChildren">
        <all>
            <element name="category_id" type="xsd:int"/>
            <element name="parent_id" type="xsd:int"/>
            <element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
            <element name="is_active" type="xsd:int"/>
            <element name="position" type="xsd:int"/>
            <element name="icecat_id" type="xsd:int"/>
            <element name="level" type="xsd:int"/>
        </all>
    </complexType>

        <complexType name="catalogCategoryTree">
            <all>
                <element name="category_id" type="xsd:int"/>
                <element name="parent_id" type="xsd:int"/>
                <element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="position" type="xsd:int"/>
                <element name="level" type="xsd:int"/>
                <element name="icecat_id" type="xsd:int"/>
                <element name="children" type="typens:ArrayOfCatalogCategoryEntities"/>
            </all>
        </complexType>
```

When I make the soap call

```
$result = $proxy->catalogCategoryTree($sessionId);
$tmp = objectToArray($result);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($tmp);
```

When I see the results there are entries for the custom attribute but there are null values there.

What mistake i done?

I followed this http://www.scriptscoop.net/t/479f4a4d39bc/php-magento-api-v2-retrieve-custom-attribute-within-soap-call-catalogcateg.html

Comment: thee is also answer in the link check that too..

Comment: I followed but still it's showing null only

Comment: did you added `->addAttributeToSelect('IceCatID');` in collection

Comment: in api.php?????

Comment: yes   If you look up a few lines around line 99:

Comment: I see that when creating the attribute, you've used the wrong setup model. Sales for creating a Catalog attribute, maybe some default values aren't set in the database. Try to create a valid Magento module, use the correct setup backend, update the attribute and see how it goes

Comment: can you please suggest any reference