# Magento get Seller SKU In Back end

Tags: magento-1.9

We are using Marketplace in my website also some product have more then one seller. Even every seller have unique **SKU**

In Back end Sales Order page it showing Base seller **Sku** Only

How to fetch Assign seller SKU

```
<div><strong><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('SKU') ?>:</strong> <?php echo implode('<br />', Mage::helper('catalog')->splitSku($this->htmlEscape($this->getSku()))); ?>
```

Comment: you need to provide markeplace code details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml
```

to load sku you can get for order id and pass to collection

```
 $orderid=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
    $_collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
        $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$orderid); 

        foreach($_collection as $res){
          $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');




     $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('mpassignproduct'=>'marketplace_assignproduct'))->where('mpassignproduct.mpassignproduct_id_id=?', $res->getMpassignproductId()
     )
     ;
     $mpassignproduct =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord); 
     if(count($mpassignproduct)) {
     foreach($mpassignproduct as $assignproduct)
       { 
        $sku=$assignproduct['sku'];
       }

     }else {
    $sku=$_item->getSku();
    }}
```

Comment: can you please look this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96353/i-make-the-soap-call-catalogcategoryinfo-call

Comment: if i place two product same sku only showing in both product

Comment: Can you please check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98189/file-location-of-order-approve-mail

Answer (score 1):

Add bellow code in your files

```
<?php if ($_item = $this->getItem()): ?>
<?php $order = $_item->getOrder() ?>
<?php $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$order->getId()); 
?>
    <h5 class="title"><span id="order_item_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>_title"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></span></h5>
    <?php foreach($collection as $res) : ?>
        <?php $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
              $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');
              $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('mpassignproduct'=>'marketplace_assignproduct'))->where('mpassignproduct.mpassignproduct_id_id=?', $res->getMpassignproductId()
         );
            $mpassignproduct =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord); 
         ?>
         <?php if(count($mpassignproduct)):?>
                <?php foreach($mpassignproduct as $assignproduct):?> 
                    <div><strong><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('SKU') ?>:</strong> <?php echo implode('<br />', Mage::helper('catalog')->splitSku($this->htmlEscape($this->getSku()))); ?></div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
         <?php else: ?>
                <div><strong><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('SKU') ?>:</strong> <?php echo implode('<br />', Mage::helper('catalog')->splitSku($this->htmlEscape($this->getSku()))); ?></div>
         <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php if ($this->getOrderOptions()): ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
        <?php foreach ($this->getOrderOptions() as $_option): ?>
            <dt><?php echo $_option['label'] ?></dt>
            <dd>
            <?php if (isset($_option['custom_view']) && $_option['custom_view']): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getCustomizedOptionValue($_option); ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php $_option = $this->getFormattedOption($_option['value']); ?>
                <?php echo $_option['value']; ?><?php if (isset($_option['remainder']) && $_option['remainder']): ?><span id="<?php echo $_dots = 'dots' . uniqid()?>"> ...</span><span id="<?php echo $_id = 'id' . uniqid()?>"><?php echo $_option['remainder'] ?></span>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('<?php echo $_id ?>').hide();
                    $('<?php echo $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?php echo $_id ?>').show();});
                    $('<?php echo $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?php echo $_dots?>').hide();});
                    $('<?php echo $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?php echo $_id ?>').hide();});
                    $('<?php echo $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?php echo $_dots ?>').show();});
                    </script>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </dd>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getDescription()) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```